# Splitting and Adding Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to remove the last two elements then add a 2 to the end of the array.  But, keep getting an error.  First test works then my second fails.

```
var userArray = [4, 2, 8, 5, 0, 1, 6]; // Tests may use different array values

/* Your solution goes here */
userArray.splice(5, 2, 2);
```

CORRECT:  Testing the final value of userArray when the initial array is [4, 2, 8, 5, 0, 1, 6]
Yours
4,2,8,5,0,2

INCORRECT:  Testing the final value of userArray when the initial array is [-5, 3]
Yours and expected differ. See highlights below.
Yours
-5,3,2
Expected
2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> // Tests may use different array values

Your answer should be: userArray.splice(userArray.length-2, 2, 2);

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1]

arr.splice(-2, 2, 2)

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

tried this and workd.. had to ensure the array had more than 2 elements first..

```
function trimLast2elements(ar){ 
   if(ar.length > 2){
     index = ar.length - 2 //get first index of last 2 elements.. 
     ar.splice(index, 2, 2);    
     return ar; //return array.
   }else{
     //function if array count is less
   }
}
```

apply function when needed.